# Rails webpack error: 3rd party gem cannot resolve jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack

I have a third party gem, thredded, that tries to access jQuery when I require it in my application.js.
When I load it in my application.js as seen below, I get an error.

```
require("thredded_imports.js")
import jQuery from "jquery";
```

The error I get is:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in 'C:\Ruby26-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.6.0\gems\thredded-0.16.16\app\assets\javascripts\thredded\components'
```

It appears that the issue is that Webpack is not able to access my node_modules folder as I get several of these messages for different folders in my path that are not node_modules

```
C:\Ruby26-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.6.0\gems\thredded-0.16.16\app\assets\javascripts\thredded\components\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
```

I have tried to configure my webpack.config.js to add node_modules but it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = env => {
    let prod = env !== undefined && env.production === true;
    return {
        devtool: prod ? 'source-map' : 'eval-cheap-module-source-map',

        entry: {
            'app': 'app.js',
            'sign-up': 'sign-up.js'   
        },

        devServer: {
            contentBase: './dist',
            index: 'event-create.html'
        },

        externals: {
            // require("jquery") is external and available
            //  on the global var jQuery
                'jquery': 'jQuery'
        },

        resolve: {
                modules: [
                "node_modules",
                path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules')
                ],
                alias: {
                        jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
                }
        },

        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'), 
            filename: prod ? "js/[name].[chunkhash].js" : "js/[name].js"
        },

    }
}
```

environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const erb = require('./loaders/erb')

const webpack = require('webpack');
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))

environment.loaders.append('expose', {
  test: require.resolve('jquery'),
  use: [{
    loader: 'expose-loader',
    options: '$'
  }, {
    loader: 'expose-loader',
    options: 'jQuery',
  }]
})

environment.loaders.prepend('erb', erb)
module.exports = environment
```

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.11.2",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.3.3",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/actiontext": "6.0.2-1",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "ahoy.js": "^0.3.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartkick": "^3.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-ujs": "^1.2.2",
    "local-time": "^2.1.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.6",
    "rails-erb-loader": "^5.5.2",
    "trix": "1.0.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out by explicitly setting the path in my environment.js

```
const path = require('path');

const webpack = require('webpack');
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, '../../node_modules', 'jquery')),
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))
```

Comment: This saved me a ton of time. Webpack compile was hanging after following Thredded's instructions for Rails 6 with webpacker. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're missing the following in *environment.js*, before the *exports*:

```
environment.loaders.append('expose', {
  test: require.resolve('jquery'),
  use: [{
    loader: 'expose-loader',
    options: '$'
  }, {
    loader: 'expose-loader',
    options: 'jQuery',
  }]
})
```

and *npm install* **expose-loader**, in order to expose jQuery.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work. I have posted the full environment.js

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `require.resolve("jquery")` to get the absolute path

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $:      require.resolve("jquery"),
  jQuery: require.resolve("jquery")
}))
```